# Gradle plugin copy file from plugin jar

Tags: plugins, resources, jar, task, gradle

I'm creating my first gradle plugin. I'm trying to copy a file from the distribution jar into a directory I've created at the project. Although the file exists inside the jar, I can't copy it to the directory.

This is my task code:

```
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction;

class InitTask extends DefaultTask {

  File baseDir;

  private void copyEnvironment(File environments) {
    String resource =     getClass().getResource("/environments/development.properties").getFile();
    File input = new File(resource);
    File output = new File(environments, "development.properties");

    try {
      copyFile(input, output);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) {
    destFile << sourceFile.text
  }

  @TaskAction
  void createDirectories() {
    logger.info "Creating directory."

    File environments = new File(baseDir, "environments");
    File scripts = new File(baseDir, "scripts");
    File drivers = new File(baseDir, "drivers");

    [environments, scripts, drivers].each {
      it.mkdirs();
    }

    copyEnvironment(environments);

    logger.info "Directory created at '${baseDir.absolutePath}'."
  }
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
:init
java.io.FileNotFoundException:     file:/path-to-jar/MyJar.jar!/environments/development.properties (No such     file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at groovy.util.CharsetToolkit.<init>(CharsetToolkit.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.newReader(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:15706)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.getText(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:14754)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$352.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GeneratedMetaMethod$Proxy.doMethodInvoke(GeneratedMetaMethod.java:70)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3465)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
    at br.com.smartcoders.migration.tasks.InitTask.copyFile(InitTask.groovy:29)
```

Just to emphasize, the development.properties is inside the environments directory inside the MyJar.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getClass().getResource()` returns a URL. To access that URL, you'll have to read it directly  (e.g. with `url.text`) rather than first converting it to a String/File. Or you can use `getClass().getResourceAsStream().text`, which is probably more accurate. In both cases you can optionally specify the file encoding.

Comment: Hi @peter! It worked!

this is the new copyEnvironment method:

     void copyEnvironment(environments) {
        String resource = InitTask.class.getResourceAsStream("/environments/development.properties").text;
        File output = new File(environments, "development.properties");
    
        output << resource  
      }

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin DSL answer!
For cases like this it is good to have extensions:

```
fun Any.getResource(filename: String): File? {
    val input = this::class.java.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(filename) ?: return null

    val tempFile = File.createTempFile(
        filename.substringBeforeLast('.'),
        "." + filename.substringAfterLast('.')
    )
    tempFile.deleteOnExit()

    tempFile.writer().use { output ->
        input.bufferedReader().use { input ->
            output.write(input.readText())
        }
    }

    return tempFile
}
```